# Regex match first digit and illegal characters

Tags: regex

Im trying to match illegal characters /\W/ and if the first character is a digit, so something like a variable name validator.

For example in this string: 
`1ThisConta!@#insI.nvalidC.hars`

I want to match 
`[1]ThisConta[!@#]insI[.]nvalidC[.]hars`

I tried this `/^\d?\W/` but somehow it does not work.

Comment: What is an "illegal" character?

Comment: Everything that matches \W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do:

```
/(^\d|\W)/g
```